# I am using spinner for displaying names of subject on spinner in row infater

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-spinner

I am using `Spinner` for displaying names of subject on `Spinner` in row inflater. When I select first value of `Spinner`then that value  need to hide on next row `Spinner`.

```
if (subjectpkey.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

    for (int p=0;p<2;p++) {
        View child = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.rowacademic, null);
        mContainerView.addView(child);

        Spinner subjectspinner = (Spinner) child.findViewById(R.id.fragmenttwelve_spinner_subjectspinner);

        subjectadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sub);
                        subjectadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        subjectspinner.setAdapter(subjectadapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just hide or remove ? Are you using an adapter with a List ?

Comment: Only hide the value... and value come from server and i stored that value in array

Comment: Try this `subjectspinner.getChildAt(theIndexOfYourItem).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: its hide row.. i want to hide value in spinner...